# Is there a way to input hundreds of variables into SAS without using each variable separately?

Tags: input, sas

I have a set of data of gym membership starting with an ID, then 119 in-time columns and 119 out-time columns.  The in-time and out-time columns are in the syntax of ##:##:## and I am trying to input the variables in the simplest way.  Rather than writing [ID in1 $ in2 $ inX $ out1 $ out2 $ outX $], is there a way to easily input hundreds of columns in a simple line of code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read in data or test something? What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 3):

Just use variable lists.  Let's assume your data file is comma delimited.

```
data want ;
  infile 'myfile.csv' dsd truncover ;
  input id (in1-in119 out1-out119) (:time8.) ;
  format in1-in119 out1-out119 time8.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

"proc import" can be an alternative solution.
It defines data type automatically.

The statement looks like the following:

```
proc import 
   datafile = myfile.csv
   out = work.destination_table
   dbms = csv replace
;
run;
```